# why doesn't my static lib function return an integer?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't get my objC static lib function _init_and_test to return the integer 234.
The app that imports the lib and calls _init_and_test gets integer 1 instead.

I import lib to the app by clicking and dragging lib's .a & .h from Xcode lib window into app window.

UPDATE 1:

I set breakpoint at "int num = ..." and step into _init_and_test, but debugging immediately goes to final curly brace instead of stepping through the instructions. And when it steps back out, I hover over num and it's = 1.

```
//
//  test_lib.h
//  test_lib
//


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface test_lib : NSObject
-(int)_init_and_test;

@end



//
//  test_lib.m
//  test_lib
//


#import "test_lib.h"

@implementation test_lib

-(int)_init_and_test
{

int a = 234;
return a;
}

@end


//
//  ViewController.h
//  test_app
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "test_lib.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end



//
//  ViewController.m
//  test_app
//
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    test_lib* test_lib_instance;

    if( !test_lib_instance ) test_lib_instance = [[ test_lib alloc] init];

    int num =[ test_lib_instance   _init_and_test ];  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< num = 1 instead of 234

 . . .
```

Comment: I don't think your question contains enough information to help debug. Did you try setting a breakpoint on `-[test_lib _init_and_test]` to see if the code is run as you expect?

Comment: I set breakpoint at "int num = ..." and can step into _init_and_test, but when it steps back out, I hover over num and it's = 1.

Comment: UPDATED: I set breakpoint at "int num = ..." and step into _init_and_test, but debugging immediately goes to final curly brace instead of stepping through the instructions. And when it steps back out, I hover over num and it's = 1.

Comment: Just after ```int num = [test_lib_instance ...``` add ```NSLog( @"instance %p num %d", test_lib_instance, num );``` and post output.

Comment: Can you try looking at the disassembly while you’re stepping through? Otherwise can you share more about your build setup? Nothing seems obviously wrong here.

Comment: skaak: Done.  It logged:  2020-12-04 18:06:12.530590-0800 test_app[2287:2287336] instance 0x283d48850 num 1

Comment: when declaring a **NSObject** without alloc/init or new set it **nil** otherwise the variable is pointing at a random piece of stack. It is more safe and good practice to do `test_lib* test_lib_instance = nil;`. The exact same thing is often reason for leaks in example with `NSError *error;` which should be `NSError *error = nil;`. Even worse, some do: ( `NSError *error = NULL;`) which is just wrong! its like a guaranteed leak.

Comment: jtbandesI only created an empty ObjC static lib and an empty ObjC single view app.  IOS Deploymen Target = 13.6 for both.

Comment: Ol Sen: that didn't work.

Comment: Its not the underscores that are causing trouble?

Comment: I can't think of any good reason for this, if the code is actually getting executed.  The only thing I can think of is that the compiler might be doing something special for methods with "init" in them, expecting them to return an instance of the class.  test_lib_instance will only start as nil in ARC mode (non-ARC it will be uninitialized garbage and probably crash), but don't think that is your problem.  It's almost as if the value is being interpreted as a boolean.  Seems like a long shot, but try renaming the method to not have "init" ?